# WYSIWYG Editor dissapears after ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, html, sql, ajax

I am using Froala WYSIWYG editor and I am having problems after an ajax request to get new content form a SQL database. I can't find a solution at the documentation of the editor.

This is the code I use for starting the editor into a  inside a userform.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#message').editable()
    });
</script>
```

Code works fine, then I make an ajax request to load content into the , but after the request, I cannot make the editor load correctly.

The request page just connects to the database, gets content and outputs something like (code is very simplified):

```
<textarea id="message">$sqlRow["message"]</textarea>
```

I have tried also $(document).ready(function() { with same bad result.

Probably I am doing something wrong, related to elements not being correctly loaded into the DOM?

I really don't know!

I hope we can figure it out! Thanks!

Comment: Try: https://www.raptor-editor.com/ (full disclosure)

Comment: what errors in browser debugger?

Comment: @Petah, thanks but I am not planning on changing the editor.

Comment: @halkujabra, No errors shown at the browser as far as I can see. The code is outputted correctly...

Comment: No. Press F12 on browser. It will open browser dev tool. Then refresh. It will show you errors on console.

Comment: @halkujabra Yes. I know how to access the error console... No error on Firefox, no errors on Safari. Nothing is shown because the code works, the editor is not initializing for some other reason I don't know...

Comment: hm then you should focus on asking on editor forums.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the looks of it your replacing the textarea in Javascript, this would cause the WYSIWYG editor to turn back into a normal textarea.

Either:

- Get just the message from the server, and then do `$('#message').html()` (maybe better way to do it in the WYSIWYG documentation)
- Re-run the WYSIWYG init code after the ajax call.

Comment: I was trying your second answer, but I realized it was in the wrong place... I have now placed it after the ajax call, and it is working! Thanks!